# Trying to remember a story about a guy that goes back in time and brings mythical creatures to the future

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to remember the title of a story where a man is sent back in time to collect extinct animals for his era's zoo. For some reason, he only locates and brings back mythical creatures. I read it in the 1980's.

Comment: For the record, Niven stated (a bit tongue in cheek) that the reason he keeps getting mythological creatures is that time travel is fantasy, not science fiction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sounds like "The Flight of the Horse", by Larry Niven.  Published 1969, it was the first of a few short stories starring Hanville Svetz, agent from a badly confused future sent back to retrieve (usually misidentified) animals from the past.

There were about five stories in this series, [reprinted as a collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Flight_of_the_Horse) in 1975.

They were republished, with a new novella added, as [Rainbow Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Mars) in 1999.

Comment: Dude! That's it. That has to be a record for the best response time ever.

Comment: (when I read it, it was titled "Get a horse", but you nailed it. I know what I'm getting at the used bookstore.)

Comment: *Rainbow Mars* is a collection of five of these stories, plus a novella.